# What does this weird icon mean on Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Intellij was previously perfectly working for me. However today, I logged in and every class in my modules had the following icon
[image]

This icon is not on the jetbrains symbol page.

Comment: This is not strictly a programming question, so possibly a little offtopic here. Apart from that, the symbol shows the usual file icon with a 'j' in it. Regarding the context (Java development), it's likely that this means a File containing Java code, but IntelliJ has not been able to parse the contained class yet, possibly because there isn't one.

Comment: "Java file", according to the documentatin: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-types-recognized-by-intellij-idea.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ will show the "Java file" icon when it is a Java file, but it is not on the source path of your project.

Answer (score 0):

This icon appears when you comment out all the contents of your java class. Like when you do
`ctrl+a` then `ctrl+shift+/`

Comment: This appears for _all_ java class' in my programme. Weird :s